# I get a cookie that contains a Session Token from my Login WS call ?

Tags: android, web-services, post, cookies, web

It always gives me the login page, as a response, because, it doesn't see me as logged in.
This is the code for my POST method ( i call it both on the login and other web services):

```
protected WebEntity sendPOST(WebServiceTask.InputParam param) throws Exception {
    WebEntity result = null;
    httppost = new HttpPost(param.url);

    if ((param.nameValuePairs != null) && !param.nameValuePairs.isEmpty()) {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param.nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
        LogService.log("sendPOST", "======params========" + param.nameValuePairs);
    }
    System.out.println("----blabla_session : "+blabla_session);
    if (blabla_session != null) {
        CookieStore cookieStore = httpclient.getCookieStore();
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("blabla_session", blabla_session);
        cookie.setDomain("http://blbla.kz");
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
        httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        httppost.setHeader("Set-Cookie", blabla_session);


    }
    LogService.log("WEB-SERVER-CLIENT POST : ", httppost.getURI().toString());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 400) {
        String maybeThereIsSomeExtraMessageInBody = "";
        try {
            maybeThereIsSomeExtraMessageInBody = (String) getResponseStream(response, response.getEntity(), String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // DO NOTHING
        }
        return new WebEntity(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() + "\n" + maybeThereIsSomeExtraMessageInBody);
    }
    Header cp = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie");
    if(cp!=null){
        HeaderElement[] he = cp.getElements();
        for (int i = 0; i < he.length; i++) {
            if(he[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("blabla_session")){
                blabla_session = he[i].getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (responseEntity != null) {
        if (result != null) {
            result.success = true;
        } else {
            result = new WebEntity(false);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now the first WS call i do, is the Login WS, at this time, blabla_session is null, so that part of the code, does not initiate. From the second WS call, the blabla_session (which is static) is initiated with the necesary session_code, i get from the session. This is why, it enters the (blabla_session != null) part of code, where it should create the cookie, to send with the WS call

This is the code they use for the WebService, i call:

```
r = requests.post('http://blabla.kz/api/login/',data={'username':'USERNAME','password':'123'})
rr = requests.get('http://blabla.kz/api/validate_coupon/bsdfsdfsd/', cookies=r.cookies)
rr.text
```

Comment: I get the data needed from the login, the problem is that my code does not send any cookie, with the validate call. How do i send a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i was invoking the webservice call, i had a parameter that shouldn;t be there, in the nameValuePairs, and that is why it was crashing